# Zoho API file upload error "Unable to process your request. Please verify whether you have provided proper file."

Tags: api, zoho

I want to upload file to zoho using uploadFile method, but unfortunately i got this :

"Unable to process your request. Please verify whether you have entered proper method name,parameter and parameter values."

```
$fields = array();
$fields['content'] = '@' . $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

This process provided from zoho..

Please go to Setup-->Extensions & APIs-->APIs-->CRM API-->Click on Gear Icon-->Authentication Token Regeneration. Now, try to initiate an API call using the newly generated auth token.

Zoho forums Link : [Zoho CRM->Zoho CRM Developer APIs](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/unable-to-process-your-request-please-verify-whether-you-have-entered-proper-method-name-parameter-and-parameter-values)

**Edited :**
Finally got solution :

Need to be change :-

```
$post['content'] = '@' . $content;
```

to

```
$post['content'] = new CurlFile($content);
```

Comment: It's work for me before. But currently it's dose not work .

Comment: If it is not working, why did you answer your own question with a wrong answer?